# Why do major earthquakes keep happening in Lombok recently?

Tags: earthquakes, seismology, seismic-hazards

So I've been following the situation in [Lombok, Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lombok) from both online news and friends on the ground. One thing that I can't seem to figure out is why there are [so many earthquakes over an extended period of time](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/map/#%7B%22autoUpdate%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22basemap%22%3A%22grayscale%22%2C%22feed%22%3A%221534712794451%22%2C%22listFormat%22%3A%22default%22%2C%22mapposition%22%3A%5B%5B-9.663030792615071%2C114.64233398437499%5D%2C%5B-7.623886853120036%2C118.157958984375%5D%5D%2C%22overlays%22%3A%5B%22plates%22%5D%2C%22restrictListToMap%22%3A%5B%22restrictListToMap%22%5D%2C%22search%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%221534712794451%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Search%20Results%22%2C%22isSearch%22%3Atrue%2C%22params%22%3A%7B%22starttime%22%3A%222018-07-01%2000%3A00%3A00%22%2C%22endtime%22%3A%222018-08-19%2023%3A59%3A59%22%2C%22maxlatitude%22%3A-7.994%2C%22minlatitude%22%3A-9.297%2C%22maxlongitude%22%3A117.081%2C%22minlongitude%22%3A115.719%2C%22minmagnitude%22%3A5%2C%22orderby%22%3A%22time%22%7D%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%22newest%22%2C%22timezone%22%3A%22utc%22%2C%22viewModes%22%3A%5B%22list%22%2C%22map%22%5D%2C%22event%22%3Anull%7D)?

Is it common for there to be earthquakes for a whole month and of high magnitudes too in seismic zones?

I have read that there can be aftershocks but I don't think that all these quakes can be characterized as aftershocks of the initial quake? These quakes seem to be independent quakes and not a continuation of aftershocks.

The major 3 have also been progressing from the south to the northwest to the northeast of the island as though it is following some pattern. So is this a sign that an underlying seismic development such as a major shift in tectonic plates or a new volcano formation will take place?

Please explain it to me like I'm 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is quite possible to have a number of earthquakes over an extended period of time.

The phenomenon is actually quite common. Some famous sequences are: New Madrid in 1811-1812, Eastern California Shear Zone (1992-1999), Italy (2009-2016), New Zealand (2010-2011) etc. These are all areas where rates of seismicity are relatively low so a number of events in quick succession (as you saw in Lombok) is not due to pure chance.

The idea of one earthquake triggering another on a neighboring or nearby faults is not new.